# OpenPGP.min.js doesn't generate key pair

Tags: javascript, pgp, openpgp

I'm since yesterday trying to make the [openpgp.js](http://openpgpjs.org/) work. I tried the full version, but no success, so right now I tried the min version, and still no success. I have the following HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OpenPGPJS Unit Tests</title>
    <script src="openpgp.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
my_user_id = "John Test <john_test@someserver.com>";
my_passphrase = "123qwe";
my_key = openpgp.generateKeyPair({numBits: 1024, userId: my_user_id, passphrase:    
my_passphrase});

// My Private Key String
console.log("My private key:\n\n" + my_key.privateKeyArmored + "\n\n");

// My Public Key String
console.log("My public key:\n\n" + my_key.publicKeyArmored + "\n\n");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But in my Chrome's console, I get only:

```
My private key:

undefined


poc.html:17 My public key:

undefined
```

Why it's undefined?

Comment: They are using promises for their methods. So try to use something like `openpgp.generateKeyPair(...).then(function(keyPair) {...})`

Comment: Hum... Sorry but I don't know what you mean. Anyway I tried something like this right now, and just got few different errors. Could you post some working example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library uses [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).
To get your generated keys you will have to use the `.then()` method of the returned promise:

```
var my_user_id = "John Test <john_test@someserver.com>";
var my_passphrase = "123qwe";
var my_key = openpgp
                .generateKeyPair({numBits: 1024, userId: my_user_id, passphrase: my_passphrase})
                .then(function(keyPair) {
                    console.log("privateKeyArmored: " + keyPair.privateKeyArmored);
                });
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm not a JS coder, will look further for this promises thing. Thank you.